# export keys and values of dictionary as variable name and value

Tags: julia

How could I create variables from keys and values of a dictionary? Is the following extract (like PHP) possible?

```
julia> d = Dict(
    "key1"    =>111,
    "key2"    =>222,
    "key3"    =>333
);
julia> extract(d)
julia> key1, key2, key3
(111,222,333)
```

Comment: Look at mauro3's package Parameters.jl (https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl). Specifically, unpacking a Dict is the way this operation is described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to introduce new variables into the *global* scope with `eval`:

```
julia> x = 1
1

julia> function testeval()
           eval(:(x = 5))
           return x
       end
testeval (generic function with 1 method)

julia> testeval()
5

julia> x # the global x has changed!
5
```

An `extract` function could look like this:

```
julia> function extract(d)
           expr = quote end
           for (k, v) in d
               push!(expr.args, :($(Symbol(k)) = $v))
           end
           eval(expr)
           return
       end

julia> extract(d)

julia> key1, key2, key3
(111,222,333)
```

Note that every module has its own global scope. Therefore, this will introduce the variables into the scope of the module where the `extract` function is defined, i.e., into the `Main` module if defined at the REPL as in the example.

You should be very careful when using `eval` and first consider other approaches, e.g, the ones mentioned by David P. Sanders and Dan Getz.

Comment: It's great! Thanks for your warning! I currently only use this for creating global constants from a json file at the start of a program, your function fit that purpose well. I modified yours into ```push!(expr.args, :(const $(Symbol(k)) = $v))```. Then I'll get ```WARNING: redefining constant key1``` if I modify its value.

Answer (score 3):

```
k = collect(keys(d)) 

v = collect(values(d))
```

Both keys and values return iterators. 
collect then produces an array.

But note that you often do not need to do this and can just iterate through the dictionary using

```
for (k, v) in d
```